# cudaFree and cudaFreeHost fails to free heap allocated memory

Tags: c++, oop, cuda

I have written a class in which constructor memory in a heap is allocated with cudaMallocHost() and cudaMalloc().

If I try to free memory cudaFree() or cudaFreeHost(), GPUassert complains:

> GPUassert: invalid device pointer ../src/main.cu 97

or

> GPUassert: invalid argument ../src/main.cu 95

I am using CUDA TK 7.0 on a device with compute capability 2.1.

I guess I am missing something fundamental. 
Can I create objects which allocate memory on device?

```
class FreeMe {

public:
    FreeMe(int size);
    ~FreeMe(void);

private:
    float *A, *dA;
    int size;
};

FreeMe::FreeMe(int size) :
        size(size) {
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocHost((void** ) &A, sizeof(float) * size));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void** ) &dA, sizeof(float) * size));
}
FreeMe::~FreeMe(void) {
    std::cout << "FreeMe obj deleted: Free ..." << std::endl;
    gpuErrchk(cudaFreeHost(A));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(dA));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int size = 3;

    FreeMe free1(size);

    cudaDeviceReset();
    std::cout << "Program terminated successfully." << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you need initialize CUDA first.

Comment: Also looks like cudaFreeHost is called after cudaDeviceReset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is caused by you call to `cudaDeviceReset()`. Looking at [its documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_gdcc2c6f914eb9461565b12648faa5e28.html):

> Explicitly destroys and cleans up all resources associated with the
>   current device in the current process. Any subsequent API call to this
>   device will reinitialize the device.
>
> Note that this function will reset the device immediately. It is the
>   caller's responsibility to ensure that the device is not being
>   accessed by any other host threads from the process when this function
>   is called.

Note that your object will be destroyed **after** that call. As you have reset your device then, it won't be able to deallocate memory (which is done inside the destructor).

One solution would be to allocate your object on heap using `new` and `delete`, therefore you could `delete` your `free1` object **before** call to `cudaDeviceReset()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, was completely oblivious of the scope.